# What was the practical effect of voter suppression in the UK's 2019 EU parliament elections?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, european-parliament, ukip, voting

There are reports of widespread voter suppression of both non-UK EU-citizens and UK citizens living outside the UK in the 2019 EU Parliament elections, which they are entitled to participate in.

[Channel 4](https://www.channel4.com/news/eu-citizens-complain-of-being-denied-right-to-vote-in-uk-european-elections)
[Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/may/23/eu-citizens-denied-vote-european-election-polling-booths-admin-errors)
[BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-48384000)

What are the practical consequences of this in terms of MEPs returned?

This group, exercising their freedom of movement, are unlikely to have voted for a party that want to remove that freedom. Could this group have changed a "winning" UKIP-Brexit Party candidate to another party, were they were allowed to vote?

Comment: Don't forget Britons living abroad too. https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/eu-elections-expats-uk-british-europe-brexit-germany-spain-a8927171.html

Comment: @Jontia - Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the result could have been different, but given the voting system used in the UK for European elections, it appears it would have taken a large number of additional votes, very specifically arranged to cause it to happen.

Taking the results from [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_2019_European_Parliament_election_in_the_United_Kingdom#South_East_England_(10_seats)) and applying the [D'Hondt system of PR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method) to the votes in each electoral region we find :

- In the South East of England the 9th seat went to the Labour party with a quota of 184,678 votes (which was their total share, this was their first seat). Meanwhile Change UK received no seats for 105,832. Hence about 80,000 would have been enough.
- In London, a very similar total would have flipped a Brexit party seat to Change UK.
- In the East Midlands about 26,000 votes would have flipped a Brexit Party seat to the Greens
- In the West Midlands about 50,000 votes would have flipped a Conservative seat to the Liberal Democrats.
- In Yorkshire 96,000 votes would have flipped a seat from the Brexit party to the Liberal Democrats

I'm afraid I don't understand Northern Ireland politics well enough to try and work out what would need to happen under their STV system. In Scotland about 36,000 votes would have flipped a seat from the Conservatives to Labour, but I'm not sure that's actually a pro-Remain move.

Comment: Part of the problem also is that the UK is one of the few EU countries (the others being Ireland and Poland, and to a lesser degree Belgium) where voting occurs in small enough [constituencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Parliament_constituency) that minority parties get suppressed.

Comment: A more simplistic view is that nationally the LibDems require an additional 2 million votes to Overtake the Brexit Party , https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/topics/crjeqkdevwvt/the-uks-european-elections-2019. That's roughly the same number of Votes that the Green Party got.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Although the system also allows regional parties such as the SNP and Plaid Cymru representation they would lose in a single constituency system.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Although actually the distinction I was intending was between D'Hondt and  Sainte-Laguë, which would have made it much easier for a party such as Change UK to pick up seats.

Comment: @origimbo: There's nothing wrong IMO with breaking out separate constituencies for Scotland, Ireland, and Wales. It's the size of constituencies in England (under 5 MEPs in several cases) that, to me, reeks of gerrymandering under a different name by the two main parties. Italy accommodates its local particularists while avoiding that problem, by having much larger constituencies than those in the UK or Poland.